# Android webview not filling device screen

Tags: android, webview

My view doesn't fill the whole screen, I see a white background at the sides. This is my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.simarkets.app_1.MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Comment: Remove your 4 padding lines..

Comment: you re right thank you verry much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove all the padding that are set by default. When you create a new android project with an activity, the tool that generates the code create an activity with padding set to 5dp. If you want to remove it, you have to remove this

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

And in addition it will be good to remove this dimensions from the resource files too.

Also if you want to make your `WebView` to be full screen, you can simply define it as a root element of your activity:

```
<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Comment: Welcome :) Happy to read that it was useful. May I ask you to accept the answer if you think it is the best one?

Comment: its useful but not the best :) the best is the first comment on my question but i don't think i can mark it as the best answer so i mark yours thank you again

Comment: Have you tried the second part of my answer - removing the whole RleativeLayout and leave the WebView as a root element of the layout file? I think this is the best approach if you want to stretch WebView on the whole screen. You don't need a container. It is a bad practice to use containers where you don't need them because the deeper the hierarchy goes, the slower the layout becomes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Try this for `RelativeLayout`

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.simarkets.app_1.MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    <!--Maybe this part doesn't need-->
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it s all about the 4 padding lines they should be removed

Comment: That's why I didn't put the paddings in my answer, you can use if you want your relative layout aswell, if It solved your problem mark it as a correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have padding in your RelativeLayout so remove this:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```